# For what values of x is g continuous? g(x) = 0 if x is rational. g(x) = x if x is irrational.

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-explanation

For what values of *x* is *g* continuous?

g(x) = 0 if x is rational, and g(x) = x if x is irrational.

I know the answer is "g only continuous at 0."

I guess I probably know the intuitive reason, but I can't use ε-δ definition to prove that g only continuous at 0.

Can someboy help me to figure out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint : The rational numbers as well as the irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$. Use this to show that the function is not continous for $x\ne 0$.

Comment: In this post, you have a similar function but rational and irrational numbers are exchanged. You might be able to use similar arguments as given there: [Continuity defined for rational and irrational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/416822).